# Microsoft-excel newlines and tab

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

Current I use "**CONCATENATE**" to join string in **Excel**, but I want insert character **newlines** and **tab** in string joined by "**CONCATENATE**".

**Example:**

- I've string below when I completed join string.

  `"Today is very beautiful"`
- I expected string newlines and tab auto as below:

> ```
> Today is
>       verry
>       beautiful
> ```

How to do that?

Comment: Not a solution for Excel users, but it might help someone: The spreadsheet program "Gnumeric" accepts tabs.

Answer (score 19):

As TAB cannot be displayed in Excel cell, instead of using `CHAR(9)`, in order to indent the line, I recommend using spaces. By using `REPT()` function, it will be easier to control the indent width by specifying the number of spaces (e.g. 4).

```
=CONCATENATE(A1, CHAR(10), REPT(" ", 4), A2)
```

Alternatively, I usually use `&` for concatenation to simplify the formula.

```
=A1 & CHAR(10) & REPT(" ", 4) & A2
```

Lastly, you have to format the cell as "Wrap text" by `CTRL-1` > Alignment

Answer (score 10):

You can try this formula:-

```
=CONCATENATE(A1,CHAR(10),CHAR(9),B1,CHAR(10),CHAR(9),C1)
```

Here

```
CHAR(10) - Line Feed/New Line
CHAR(9)  - Horizontal Tab
```

To see new line, you need to mark as checked on the `Wrap Text` box

Right click on Cell --> **Format Cells** --> Click on **Alignment** Tab --> Under **Text control** --> Check the box "**Wrap Text**"

*`Note: Tab spacing won't appear on the Cell`*

Comment: [Here's a link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CHAR-function-bbd249c8-b36e-4a91-8017-1c133f9b837a) to the Excel help for the `CHAR` function.

Here's the table of values that you can use on [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) and on [Mac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_Roman) via Wikipedia. It is important to note that the results may be different on each OS.

Comment: https://www.asciitable.com/ has a better chart for the first 128 characters since Excel's char function takes a decimal number.

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be no way to make

         `="some string"&char(9)&"another string"`

work.  The resulting text pasted as plain text in a txt file or a as unformated text in word is as follows:

        `"some string    another string"`

Including the unwanted double quotes.
If pasted as keep or merged formatting it is as follows:

        `some string another string`

Please note that the tab has been replaced with a single space.

If instead of char(9) a printable character such as “!” char(33) the resulting text pasted in word or a text editor is always:

        `some string!another string`

## The bottom line is:

Currently there appears to be no method to insert a tab in a cell.  This is a pity as there is a genuine need for this.  A workaround is to insert a character that isn’t expected in the cell and then use a post processer or a macro in the target editor.  I intend to use a grave (just above the tab) and a word VBA macro to convert it to a tab.

Answer (score 2):

You could try adding newline and tabs yourself, as just another text element:

```
=CONCATENATE("Today is", Chr(13), Chr(9), "verry", Chr(13), Chr(9), "beautiful"
```

whereas `Chr(13)` produces a newline and `Chr(9)` a tab.

Comment: Sorry Boy's Rules, Char(13) is a carriage return, not new line. My bad

Answer (score 1):

### Simple: Paste them from text editor as *quoted* plain text ([TSV format](https://www.google.com/search?q=tsv%20format)).

**No one mentioned this simple and obvious method so far.**

1. Create the cell content in Notepad with actual `tab` and `newline` characters. This example contains them all (here Tab is illustrated as `↹`):

   ```
   Before Tab↹AfterTab
   Second "line" of the same cell.
   ```
2. Surround the entire content with double quotes `"` (A conversion into TSV format).

   - Should be there any double quotes already inside the original text, double them. For better clarity I put them into the above example.
     The above example will now look like:

     ```
     "Before Tab↹AfterTab
     Second ""line"" of the same cell."
     ```
3. Mark the entire text (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> copy it into clipboard.
4. In Excel, navigate to the cell (but do *not* enter its edit mode) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste.

**Done.** Now the cell content is exactly as you expect it, including newlines and tabs. (You can verify it by formulas, VBA or by round trip, i.e. by copy-paste back to text file). Mandatory notices:

- You might need to increase row height to reveal the second line.
- Do not expect correct formatting of contained Tab characters. (But you know that already.) Excel is not designed to handle them properly inside the cell. Should you need left indentation of cell content, open **Format Cells** window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>) and set the **Indent** value on **Alignment** tab.

**Tip:** You can insert multiple cells by using newline and tab *outside* the quotes.

This example (two rows by two columns in TSV) will insert area of 2×2 cells at once:

```
A1↹B1
A2↹B2
```

If you see its point, you can add newlines and tabs *inside* the values:

```
"A↹1
cell"↹"B↹1
cell"
"A↹2
cell"↹"B↹2
cell"
```

Tested with Excel 2016.

Answer (score 1):

This post is old, but I wasn't able to find any satisfying answer to this question anywhere on Google, hence here's what I've come up with:

```
=CONCAT("Today is";CHAR(10);REPT(CHAR(1);2);"very";CHAR(10);REPT(CHAR(1);2);"beautiful")
```

will display as:

[image]

...which is more or less like this:

```
Today is
    very
    beautiful
```

CHAR(1) is the unprintable "Start of Heading" character in the ASCII system

Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus

Answer (score 0):

You can also use "**&**" chars to concatenate text in Excel, as below:

The clause: `=CONCATENATE(A1,CHAR(10),CHAR(9),B1,CHAR(10),CHAR(9),C1)` could be written as:

```
 =A1&CHAR(10)&CHAR(9)&B1&CHAR(10)&CHAR(9)&C1
```

This form will be interesting when CONCATENATE overflows (it has a limit of entries).